# Using ternary operator in HTML to decide on the class to be implemented

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to decide on a CSS class dynamically using ternary operator in HTML. I'm using following code but it seems the condition isn't being evaluated at all. Whatever class that is written in the true part of the condition, is applied.
How can I apply a particular class based on some condition? Any alternative approach will be helpful too.

```html
<td class="col-md-6"><span class="form-control-static cdr-details-td" />
  <span class="(('1' === '-1') ? version-modal-header : failure)">{{cdr.causeCode}}</span> 
</td>
```

CSS for the same:

```css
.version-modal-header {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.failure {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) instead

```
ng-class="{'version-modal-header': condition, 'failure': !condition}"
```

You can also use a ternary if you want

```
ng-class="condition ? 'version-modal-header' : 'failure'"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do it using the ternary operator. I had the condition ready, just had to replace class with ng-class.

Comment: `ng-class` with ternary operator really makes the job simple. Great code Phil!

Answer (score 3):

Please check working example here : [Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/SyrSF0?p=preview)

Use ng-class

```
 ng-class="{true: 'version-modal-header', false: 'failure'}[changeClass]"
```

You can write your conditions in **[changeClass]**

Comment: @User2 This was some great additional information. Cleared a few concepts too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you looking for ternary operator in style attribute in .net view pages then following answer will work for you.

style ="background-color: @(Model.IsVisible ? "#fde0e0;" : "#DFF0D8;")"

Answer (score 0):

The *ternary operation* that you have incorporated in your program, doesn't works for `class` or to be specific - HTML DOM. It can be done using AngularJS, as it provides a wonderful inbuilt `directive` knows as `ng-class`. Using this one can set the *conditions*, based on which one needs to apply the `class`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```
<td class="col-md-6"><span class="form-control-static cdr-details-td" />
    <span ng-class="{'version-modal-header': '1' === '-1', 'failure': '1' === '1'}">{{cdr.causeCode}}</span>
</td>
```

Check out the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/e4r0zz0b/).

Comment: Thanks @Shashank. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-class`  if you want to apply a css class dynamically. dont use interpolation or binding {{}} to apply css class directly as it will not work across browsers.
In `ng-class` you just need to specify an object containing class names as keys and the respective Boolean condition as values. Any class whose value evaluates to true is applied dynamically.

```
<td class="col-md-6"><span class="form-control-static cdr-details-td" />
  <span ng-class="{'version-modal-header':('1' === '-1') , 'failure': ('1' !== '-1')}">{{cdr.causeCode}}</span> 
</td>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

you can use it to show and hide content dynamically

{{condition ? 'value if true' : 'value if false'}}

Answer (score 0):

Heres a solution that worked for me.

```
<p style={{borderBottom: loginToggle ? '6px solid blue' : "None"}}></p>
```